# How many Schedules possible with given set of Transactions? Given that total ordering of operations in a transactions is there.

Tags: combinatorics

Given that :

There are $m$ transactions = $\{T_1, T_2, \dots, T_m\}$

and for each transaction $T_i$ there are $n_i$ operations in it.

It is required that the relative ordering of operations within a transaction does not change.

**How many possible Schedules can be obtained with these transactions?**

---

**example:**

a set of 2 transactions is given $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Transaction $T_1$ has operations (given in a relative order to each other) = $a_1, a_2$ and

Transaction $T_2$ has operations (in relative order to each other) = $b_1, b_2$.

a possible schedule $S_1$ = $\{b_1,a_1,a_2,b_2\}$

note that the relative ordering of $a$'s pair and $b$'s pair is still intact in the possible schedule $S_1$.

say, $S_2$ = $\{b_2, a_1, a_2, b_1\}$ here, relative ordering of operations of $T_1$ is maintained but, for $T_2$ not. So, its Invalid. We should not count such *invalid* schedules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we did not pay attention to the restriction on order of operations, there would be  $(n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_m)!$ possible schedules.

Of these, the fraction $\frac{1}{n_1!}$ have the operations of $T_1$ in the right order. Of the ones that have the operations of $T_1$ in the right order,   the fraction $\frac{1}{n_2!}$ have the operations of $T_2$ in the right order,  and so on. So the total allowed number of schedules is the multinomial coefficient 
$$\frac{(n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m)!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_m!}.$$

**Another way:** Let $N=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m$. There are $\binom{N}{n_1}$ ways to decide on the set of positions that the operations of $T_1$ will occupy, and then there is only one way to place the actual operations. Once this is done, there are $\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}$ ways to place the operations of $T_2$, and then $\binom{N-n_1-n_2}{n_3}$ ways to place the operations of $T_3$, and so on.

When we find the product of the binomial coefficients, and simplify, we get the answer obtained earlier.